# How to change (increase) resolution of QT recording?

Tags: resolution, quicktime, quality

I want to know how to increase (or change) the video resolution/quality of a Quicktime video recording on Mac. I have OS Catalina 10.15.7. Is there a way to do this? Can someone pls help? thanks.

Comment: You can choose different output settings as you set up.

Answer (score 1):

Your options are limited. Most Mac cameras (except for the 2021 iMacs) are 720p, and the settings offer "High" and "Maximum".

[image]

If you're recording the screen, then obviously you get the screen's resolution.